# android.intent.action.TIME_SET in marshmallow not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have broadcast receiver for date change event, it works fine for kitkat and lolipop version but not working in marshmallow.
code is as follow

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".DateChangedReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

what should I do for that? is their any special permission required? Please help

Answer (score 0):

You are right . This intent action may be restricted to system apps only . Adding the android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" to the receiver is working for me .
PFB update receiver definition

```
<receiver
            android:name=".DateChangedReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```